# reset a datetime jtextfield to "" by clicking on a jbutton and write it to sql server table column

Tags: java, sql-server

I have a JButton called ApprovalDate and on clicking it, a date picker frame opens and we can pick any date (which sets the jtextfiel's value) and write it to sql server table column.

I have another jbutton called Reset and on clicking it, I am able to clear the jtextfield, but when I try to write it to sql server table column, the record is not updated.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.S");
SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");


ActualApproval = jtfActualApproval.getText().trim();

 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

 cal.setTime(sdf2.parse(ActualApproval));

 ActualApproval = sdf1.format(cal.getTime());


 jbnReset.addActionListener(new ActionListener()   // Reset button’s action listener
 {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                    jtfActualApproval.setText("");     //jtextfield to be reset
            }
    });

 jbnActualApproval.addActionListener(new ActionListener()   // to open a date picker
 {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
         {
                 jtfActualApproval.setText(new DatePicker(appFrame).setPickedDate());
         }
});
```

I am not able to write "" as date field  to ms sql server table column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your database won't accept "" as a value for a DateTime-column.

Comment: I am using ms sql server 2005. It takes up default sql date which is 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 . I tried using this, but i get back my previously set date and not the reset one